# When is a span just a morphism?

Tags: category-theory

A span is a pair of arrows in the following configuration $A \leftarrow C \rightarrow B$.  I think this is a generalization of the  notion of a morphism from $A$ to $B$ and/or $B$ to $A$.  There should be a special case when the span exactly defines a morphism from $A$ to $B$ in the ambient category.  When is it the case that the span exactly defines a morphism from $A$ to $B$?

Comment: See [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/span) especially the subsection **Correspondences**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that in any way to make sense of the question, the answer will be

- When $C = A$ and $C \to A$ is the identity morphism

or possibly generalized to include the class of spans *equivalent* to spans of the above form. (which will presumably be those where $C \to A$ is an isomorphism)

For example, a binary relation can be considered as a kind of span (a *jointly monic* span; if you have products, that means $C \to A \times B$ is monic). The binary relation corresponding to the graph of a function will have a span where $C \to A$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Yah, I think I have this wrong.  Is a span more like a relation between A and B?

Comment: @BenSprott: Right; its a relation in the traditional sense it's jointly monic, or something even more general otherwise.